# Plugin updates, change file permissions on WordPress

Tags: plugins, permissions

I have a strange problem with my wordpress websites. Every time I perform plugin updates, the file permissions on my server, are changed. I get the Forbidden error in my developer console for the plugins directory that I've just update .

I use a local server with Webmin/Virtualmin to managed all my wordpress websites. So, I have virtual host for every website, and I have the same problem with all of the websites.

After updating the plugins, I have to change the file permissions, with default permissions for the wordpress, and everything works.

This are my default permissions for every wordpress website

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \
```

Comment: What does webmin/virtualmin support say?

Comment: I didn't find anything on google about this strange behavior.

Comment: So what do they need to  be, and what is WordPress setting them to? When you  say forbidden  error in  developer console, I assume you're  talking about CSS/JS assets? It's unclear

Comment: Yes, it's about css/js asset. This is an example from one site

/wp-content/plugins/eu-cookie-law/js/scripts.js?ver=3.1 net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: After plugin update, the permission is 705 for directory, and 604 for files. It remove group permissions for dirs and files

Comment: I found the issue. I will update my post

Comment: Don't update/edit your question with the answer. Instead post it as an answer (you are allowed to answer your own question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM FOUND:**

So the problem was in a separate config file. The websites were migrated from another hosting and that hosting had a separate config file which was required in the `wp-config.php` . I the other config file I found this settings:

```
define( 'FS_CHMOD_DIR', ( 0755 & ~ umask() ) );
define( 'FS_CHMOD_FILE', ( 0644 & ~ umask() ) );
```

I remove this 2 lines from config file, and everythig works fine !